# How to Convert Circle to Square image in bitmap canvas? Android Studio

Tags: android, canvas, bitmap

I need to change an image, from circle to normal square.

I'm a beginner a few weeks in programming, 
I'm 2 days stopped in this code, does anyone know how to change?

I already tried everything, but I could not solve

I do not understand anything about canvas, I've already studied to solve this problem, but I'm still not able to

```
public static Bitmap getCircleBitmap(Bitmap bitmap) {
    final int scaledWidth = 100;
    final int scaledHeight = 100;

    bitmap = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bitmap, scaledWidth, scaledHeight, true);
    Bitmap output;
    Rect srcRect, dstRect;

    float r;
    final int width = bitmap.getWidth();
    final int height = bitmap.getHeight();

    if (width > height) {
        output = Bitmap.createBitmap(height, height, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
        int left = (width - height) / 2;
        int right = left + height;
        srcRect = new Rect(left, 0, right, height);
        dstRect = new Rect(0, 0, height, height);
        r = height / 2;
    } else {
        output = Bitmap.createBitmap(width, width, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
        int top = (height - width) / 2;
        int bottom = top + width;
        srcRect = new Rect(0, top, width, bottom);
        dstRect = new Rect(0, 0, width, width);
        r = width / 2;
    }

    Canvas canvas = new Canvas(output);

    final int color = 0xff424242;
    final Paint paint = new Paint();

    paint.setAntiAlias(true);
    canvas.drawARGB(0, 0, 0, 0);


    paint.setColor(color);
    canvas.drawCircle(r, r, r, paint);
    paint.setXfermode(new PorterDuffXfermode(PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_IN));
    canvas.drawBitmap(bitmap, srcRect, dstRect, paint);

    bitmap.recycle();

    return output;

}

public static Bitmap getBitmapFromVectorDrawable(Context context, int drawableId) {
    Drawable drawable = AppCompatResources.getDrawable(context, drawableId);
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
        drawable = (DrawableCompat.wrap(drawable)).mutate();
    }

    Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(drawable.getIntrinsicWidth(),
            drawable.getIntrinsicHeight(), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
    Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bitmap);
    drawable.setBounds(0, 0, canvas.getWidth(), canvas.getHeight());
    drawable.draw(canvas);

    return bitmap;
}

}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you look at your code, towards the end of method *getCircleBitmap()* you have the below line of code:

```
canvas.drawCircle(r, r, r, paint);
```

That's the one drawing the circle image for you using [DrawCircle](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Canvas#drawCircle(float,%20float,%20float,%20android.graphics.Paint)).
What you can do is, replace it with [DrawRect](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Canvas#drawRect(float,%20float,%20float,%20float,%20android.graphics.Paint)). That should do that trick for you.

However, if you need to just draw a square image from a vector then you can use a standard *ImageView* straightaway and use the vector as image resource.

Comment: I tried change to:

canvas.drawCircle(r, r, r, paint);

But anyway, the image that is sent to the server is in a circle, and I need a square, I've tried everything, change values, but nothing

Comment: replace *drawCircle* with *drawRect*

Comment: Sorry, I wrote wrong, I tries change to: canvas.drawRect***** and isn't work :(